# Manjaro fails to boot, modules.devname not found then unknown disk UUID error

Tags: boot, manjaro

I started updating manjaro on my laptop using the package manager instead of command line (probably because of pushy notifications...) but realized in the same time that I was short on battery, I cancelled the ongoing update. It was at the very begining of the process and actually assumed that nothing had been done so far.  It is likely that this is the reason it failed to boot at the next restart.

- From an other OS I chrooted into it and finished to update the system. Even through the system did not start.
- From an other OS I chrooted into it and reinstall grub following [this](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Restore_the_GRUB_Bootloader). Then again it did not help.

There is this warning, that looks very bad when I try to start

> Warning: /lib/modules/4.9.20-1-MANJARO/modules.devname not found - ignoring

Then the error is that it fails at finding root partition by UUID but it is I think the consequence of the warning.
It then drop me into a frozen shell where I can't do anything.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an other OS, chroot into your distribution
eg from a manjaro live-CD like explained [here](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Restore_the_GRUB_Bootloader#Chroot_into_your_existing_Manjaro_Installation)

and then do

```
mkinitcpio -p linuxXX
```

eg. for me

```
mkinitcpio -p linux49
```

You can find out the version to use by having a look into `/etc/mkinitcpio.d/`

Then reboot